# Spring Security and Grails - customizing URLS

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, grails-controller, grails-config

In a current Grails app I'm working on all my account management now happens under an account controller which I would like to keep all those actions mapped under the */account/** URL pattern.

I'm using Spring Security Core. On a failed login the app still directs me to
/login/authfail?login_error=1
I want it to use
/account/authfail?login_error=1

So my question is how do I configure the default
**SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl**
and whatever the failure URL is also (I need to know the name of this property)
Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spring-security-core plugin is actually one of the best documented plugins out there.  You can find all the URL configuration options [here](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html).  Specifically, you want failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl and possibly failureHandler.ajaxAuthFailUrl.  Note that I believe these will be global changes.  So if you need to lock down other aspets of your site other than "accounts" the URL for a failed attempt will be the same as you configured it.

Comment: I was able to find it using site:burtbeckwith.github.com and then the search terms on google. thanks +1 Here is the list of props http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/13%20URL%20Properties.html I'll try this and then come back and mark the question

Comment: This line in Config.groovy worked - grails.plugins.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/account/authfail?login_error=1'

Answer (score 0):

In UrlMapping.groovy, add an instruction like :

```
"/account/$action?/$id?"{
   controller="login"
}
```

Comment: I think this would work, but wasn't the ideal way I wanted to solve it.